# Sharepoint 2010 WSP deploy wont update site

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, sharepoint-2010, wsp

Im not very used to the whole Sharepoint-thing, but usually I just simply deploy my visual studio stuffs as a wsp-package and then deploys it using PS (if I dont remember incorrect)..
Now this time I wanted to update the masterpage of my site, and add a few javascript files and update an existing javascript file.. and this time for some reason the deploy did update the allready existing javascript-file, but it didnt add the new javascriptfiles..and it didnt update the masterpage for some reason.. and I have dubble-checked that the package Im depolying contains the new files and the updated masterpage, I also checked the Elements.xml-file for the javascript files and they are there.. Any ideas?

Comment: Also to mention... I tried to deactivate the feature aswell, and the activate it.. didnt work.. and also as I deactivated the feature I tried to visit my site.. and for some reason the site worked fine(except the problem described above)..shouldnt the whole site crash if a feature(that in this case contains the masterpage) is deactivated?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you files are customized from definition (in SharePoint Designer they will have an (i) symbol. If so - revert them to definition and try to deactivate the feature again.